# Google Play Toolbar CardView

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I am trying to create a `Toolbar` with a `cardview` similar to **Google Play**.

[image]

When i try to re-create this , the cardview doesn't appear at all.

Here is a screenshot of it .

[image]

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Please tell me what went wrong here. Thanks !

Comment: I think that's actually a custom Toolbar that Google Play uses, not a CardView

Comment: For example, don't reinvent the wheel.  https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview

Comment: Please check this code and try set your code. http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2014/12/recyclerview-with-onclick-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Change AppBarLayout's background color to transparent.
And I think there is unnecessary layout hieralcy.

Following layout works in my envoriment.

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```